# Windows 8 fails to identify Wireless-G wifi network

Tags: windows-8, wireless-networking, microsoft-surface

I have been using a G-type WiFi network at my home for a few years already, and up until now, all my devices were able to connect to it without any problems. My Android phone, my Windows 8 laptop and even my HTPC all connect to it without any problem. However, I recently received a Windows Surface Pro device with Win8 (non-RT) on it, and in it's wifi networks list, I cannot see my network, although all other devices still connect to it.

If anyone knows why this might happen and how to fix it, it would be awesome ;)

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What channel is your network on? Most of the world allows channels 1-13, but North America (US and Canada) only allows channels 1-11. Most wireless cards, even for the North American market, will automatically adjust their supported channel set based on what country they think they're in, based on information in the beacon frames transmitted by the APs around them.

Maybe your Surface Pro is considering itself to be in North American mode and isn't trying to scan channels 12 and 13, so it isn't finding your AP on channel 13. If this turns out to be the case, one workaround (and way to test it) would be to put your AP on channel 1, 6, or 11.

A second possibility:
If your AP is set to not broadcast its SSID (some APs call this "hidden network" or "closed network"), then it's not supposed to show up in your network list. You're supposed to go to where you can type in a network name for it to search for. Once it has joined that network once, it might start showing it in the network list from then on.

A third possibility:
If your SSID contains characters that are not in the 7-bit ASCII character set, then the character encoding that's being used by your AP for the SSID might matter. I see from your user profile page that you're in Israel. So for example, if you'd used the old "Windows Code Page 862" encoding for Hebrew characters when you set up your AP, but the Surface Pro expects non-ASCII network names to be in Unicode, then you might be having a problem typing in the right SSID. You could be typing in the exact same Hebrew characters, but since the underlying byte values for those characters are different between Unicode and Code Page 862, the SSID isn't matching because SSID matching is based on the underlying byte values, not on the character glyphs.

Comment: Thanks for the input @Spiff, the second and third possibilities are not possible in my case since my network name is composed only of alphabetical letters and my SSID is indeed broadcasting (I've checked this with the wireless router's settings). The channel thing, however, is very likely to be the problem, since it's currently on "Automatic", I'll change this to channel 11 and see if the problem is resolved. Thanks!